# What is the use of the F# :> operator

Tags: f#

I have seen some code using the `:>` operator to accomplish something similar to *type-casting* in `C#` but even though I've searched a lot online I've seen no documentation about it.

What is that operator used for?

How does it work?

Where can I find some documentation about it?

Comment: In addition to other answers I goto the operator reference when looking for what an F# operator does: https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/symbol-and-operator-reference-[fsharp]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`:>` is the upcast operator.  It's used to cast upward in an hierarchy so it's a type of casting that can be verified at compile time.

Its counterpart `:?>` is the downcast operator but the success of this can only be resolved at runtime.

See this page for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/casting-and-conversions-[fsharp]

Comment: It might be better to point to the current version of the article in the new "official" F# documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/casting-and-conversions-%5bfsharp%5d

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev I've updated the link, thanks and sorry for sniping your answer!

Answer (score 8):

As @TheInnerLight explains, the `:>` operator represents an upcast. If you are coming from C#, this takes a bit of time to get used to, because in C# both (safe) upcast and (unsafe) downcast are written as `(SomeType)value`.

In F#, you do not need `:>` very often, because the compiler will insert automatic upcasts in the most common places - just like the C# compiler. For example, say we have `foo` that takes `obj`:

```
let foo (a:obj) = 0
```

The F# compiler accepts the following just fine, even though the argument is `Random` rather than `obj` (as the function `foo` expects):

```
foo (System.Random())
```

You could write this more explicitly, but you do not have to because the compiler inserts upcast:

```
foo (System.Random() :> obj)
```

One case where you need explicit upcasts is when returning different values from different branches of `if` or `match` constructs. For example:

```
if true then obj()
else System.Random()
```

This does not type check and you get an error:

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type `System.Object` but here has type `System.Random`

You can fix this with an explicit upcast:

```
if true then obj()
else System.Random() :> obj
```